# SQL Server 2008: Turn off select stop words for full text search query using CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search, stop-words

Have an app that was using Microsoft SQL Server and needed to search data, found that for queries that had been like "series 6" or "series 66" would return results just if they had 'series' and appears 6 was a stopword.   The app was 2008 but database compatibility level was sql server 2000 (80).

So I made backup and restored as new db, changed the compatibility to 100 (Sql Server 2008) and then ran the following:

```
ALTER DATABASE [TestDB] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON  CandidateResume SET STOPLIST = OFF
```

I then ran my query again and appears to work:

```
SELECT * FROM CandidateResume WHERE CONTAINS(CandidateResume_Resume, '"Series 6"')
```

My question, Is it possible to turn off just the numbers in the stoplist per table or do we have to do all or nothing?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280871%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is a description of ALTER FULLTEXT STOPLIST. It looks like you can DROP elements, so you could turn off numbers, but not by table.